# Letting Excel self feed web query URL

Tags: excel

I want to create a web query in an Excel template, and then update it via VBA.

Normally to create the web query I need to provide Excel a URL. 
But in my case the URL will contain the name of the file, something like *`FILEXXXX`* (with XXXX being a numeric string); the resulting URL in `FILE0001` would then look like `http://urlbabble/babblebabble_query=FILE0001`

Is there a way to let Excel generate and self feed this URL?

VBA is an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed by recording a macro and then editing the code to embed a variable in the URL

```
Sub web_query()
' web_query Macro
' This macro generates the web query used to populate sheet'
'get the file ID
FILE_ID = Sheets("intake").Range("B1")
If FILE_ID <> "" Then
    With Sheets("web_query").QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;http://url part1" 
    _& FILE_ID & "url part2", Destination:=Sheets("web_query").Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = "query=short_descriptionLIKE" & FILE_ID & "&row_count=999999999"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
        .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
        .WebDisableRedirections = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End If
End Sub
```